# Norms with complex numbers over Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $v,w \in H$ ans a be a scalar.

Prove that $\|v\| \leq \|v+aw\|$ for all scalar a iff (v,w)=0 for real and complex cases.

I want to choose a such that $\bar{a}(v,w)$ will be real and negative but "close" to zero.

Can i then say that $2Re(\bar{a}(v,w)) \leq |a|^2\|w\|^2$? How do i choose such an a?

Comment: write $w = bv + u$ with $(v,u) = 0$ and $b \ne 0$, then $\|v+aw\|^2 =\|v+abv+au \|^2= |1+ab|^2 \|v\|^2 + |a|^2 \|u\|^2$, and it reduces to $0 \le (|1+ab|^2-1)\|v\|^2 + |a|^2 \|u\|^2 =  (|1+ab|-1)(|1+ab|+1)\|v\|^2  + |a|^2 \|u\|^2$ for every $a$ which is impossible when $|1+ab|-1 < 0$ and $a$ is small enough

Comment: Why is it impossible when $|1+ab|-1<0$? I am not getting what is wrong with this statement.

Comment: because the first term is $ \sim  cst \ |a|$ whereas the other term is $cst \ |a|^2$ (same argument as Umberto)

Comment: I still don't get it. is $|ab|>>|a|^2$ for some reason?

Comment: yes of course ! when $a \to 0$ then $|a|^2 \to 0$ much faster than $C|a| $

Comment: Ok, and still i have dependencies in other terms here. this amounts to $ab(|1+ab|+1)\|v\|^2\leq |a|^2\|u\|^2$. what about the terms $\|u\|^2$ and $\|v\|^2$?

Comment: ? when $a = -\epsilon \overline{b}$ then $(|1+ab|-1)(|1+ab|+1)\|u\|^2 \sim -C |a|$ with $C = 2 |b| \|u\|^2$, the other term is $|a|^2 \|u\|^2$ and $-C |a| + |a|^2 \|u\|^2 = |a| (|a| \|u\|^2 - C) < 0$ when $a$ is small enough. what do you want to say more ?

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(v,w) \ne 0$, then choose $\alpha$ so that $(v-\alpha w)\perp w$, which is to say that $\alpha=\frac{(v,w)}{(w,w)}$. Then $\alpha\ne 0$, which leads to 
$$
          \|v\|^2=\|(v-\alpha w)+\alpha w\|^2=\|v-\alpha w\|^2+\|\alpha w\|^2 > \|v-\alpha w\|^2.
$$
Conversely, if $(v,w)=0$, then the following holds for all $\alpha$:
$$
        \|v-\alpha w\|^2=\|v\|^2+\|\alpha w\|^2 \ge \|v\|^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = t(v,w)$ for some nonzero real number $t$. Then $$2 t|(v,w)|^2 = 2 \Re (\bar a(v,w)) \le |a|^2 \|w\|^2 = t^2 |(v,w)|^2 \|w\|^2.$$

If $(v,w) \not= 0$ then $2t \le t^2 \|w\|^2$ for all nonzero real $t$, which you can quickly show is impossible.

Comment: First of all its given in the question that a is a scalar. can i still choose $a=t(v,w)$? and secondly i didn't get why can i show the last part is none true? i can divide by t and both sides and get $2 \leq t\|w\|^2$ which as far as i understand may be true. what am i missing?